# how to print all the possible trees python

Tags: python, tree, traversal

I have a tree where one node may be branching in two or more ways:

```
    A
   /  \
  B    C
 / \
D   E
   /  \
  F    G


    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \
X   Y
```

Here the node B can either have the branches **D and E**, or the branches **X and Y**.
Each node is represented as a dictionary in python. E.g. node B = {0: node with D and E as branches, 1: node with X and Y as branches}.

My question is: how do I print the two trees?

So far my program first prints A and B, and then it prints D, E, F, G, then X, Y, and finally C.

I want it to print the first tree completely, as in: **A B D E F G C**, and then start from the beginning the print the other tree **A B X Y C**. Can anyone help me with this? I've been playing with it for a whole day without any progress. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here are my test code:

```
'''
print all the possible trees
'''

class Tree():
    '''each node is a dict of Nodes, because there can be multiple parses'''
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = self.build(root)
        self.printTrees(root)

    def build(self, p):
        # p is a dict as in A = {0: ('a', B, C, False), 'terminal':False}
        if p['terminal']: # if terminal
            node = {}
            for key in p.keys():
                if key != 'terminal':
                    node[key] = Node(p[key][0], None, None, True)
            return node

        node = {}
        for key in p.keys():
            if key != 'terminal':
                node[key] = Node(p[key][0], # type
                    self.build(p[key][1]), # left
                    self.build(p[key][2])) # right
        return node

    def printTrees(self, p):
        '''TODO complete print one tree and then go to another tree!'''
        if p['terminal']: # if terminal
            for key in p.keys():
                if key != 'terminal':
                    print(p[key][0], end='  ')
            return

        for key in p.keys():
            if key != 'terminal':
                print(p[key][0])
                self.printTrees(p[key][1]) # left
                self.printTrees(p[key][2]) # right

class Node():
    def __init__(self, typ=None, left=None, right=None, terminal=False):
        self.type = typ
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.terminal = terminal

    def __str__(self):
        return "Node: "+self.type

def main():
    X = {0: ('x', None, None), 'terminal':True}
    Y = {0: ('y', None, None), 'terminal':True}

    G = {0: ('g', None, None), 'terminal':True}
    F = {0: ('f', None, None), 'terminal':True}
    D = {0: ('d', None, None), 'terminal':True}
    C = {0: ('c', None, None), 'terminal':True}

    E = {0: ('e', F, G, False), 'terminal':False}
    B = {0: ('b', D, E, False), 1: ('b', X, Y, False), 'terminal':False}
    A = {0: ('a', B, C, False), 'terminal':False}

    t = Tree(A)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: That seems like a rather weird way to create a Tree. Wouldn't it make more sense to actually use `Node`s instead of dicts? Also `'terminal'` is kind of obselete given that you can find out if it's a "leaf" by checking if a node has a left or right leaf. For your actual question: Just collect the tree "representation" in a list and in case you encounter these multi-branch make a copy and proceed with the seperate lists and just print once it's finished collecting.

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks. Yes. It would make sense to use **Node**s, but a dictionary of **Node** should still work, right? The **terminal** is indeed redundant. That's actually how I'm approaching it now. But since I'm very bad at recursions, it always leaves out something... but I think that's the right way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

To produce all the tree combinations, you can iterate over the possible children for each node (stored under the integer keys of each node dictionary), recursively call the tree building method on each of these children, `yield`ing back the results:

First, the tree setup:

```
def get_tree():
    X = {0: ('x', None, None), 'terminal':True}
    Y = {0: ('y', None, None), 'terminal':True}
    G = {0: ('g', None, None), 'terminal':True}
    F = {0: ('f', None, None), 'terminal':True}
    D = {0: ('d', None, None), 'terminal':True}
    C = {0: ('c', None, None), 'terminal':True}
    E = {0: ('e', F, G, False), 'terminal':False}
    B = {0: ('b', D, E, False), 1: ('b', X, Y, False), 'terminal':False}
    A = {0: ('a', B, C, False), 'terminal':False}
    return A
```

Then, the function to produce all the tree combinations:

```
from itertools import product
def get_trees(t):
   for a, b in t.items():
      if isinstance(a, int):
         v = [[b[0]], *[[i] if i is None else list(get_trees(i)) for i in b[1:3]]]
         yield from product(*v)

trees = list(get_trees(get_tree()))
for tree in trees:
   print(tree)
```

Output:

```
('a', ('b', ('d', None, None), ('e', ('f', None, None), ('g', None, None))), ('c', None, None))
('a', ('b', ('x', None, None), ('y', None, None)), ('c', None, None))
```